# Почему массив пустой кода я пушу туда элемент?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

```
 const tagArr = [];
  const [tagValue, setTagValue] = React.useState("");
  let obj = { value: tagValue };

  const addNewTag = () => {
    if (tagValue !== "") {
      tagArr.push(obj);
    }
  };
```

Если поставить дебаггер внутри функции `addNewTag`, то массив заполняется, но снаружи он пуст.

Comment: для изменения состояния нужно пользоваться сеттером, который возвращается из useState

Comment: @Grundy, сеттер считывает из инпута строку)

Comment: ну так приложите больше кода, почему мы должны угадывать что у вас есть а чего нету?

Answer (score 0):

а вызывать `addNewTag` пробовали?

```
addNewTag();
```

приводит к тому, что в массив данные пишутся

правда я (поскольку без реакта) сделал такой тестовый пример:

```
const tagArr = [];
const tagValue = "XXX";
let obj = { value: tagValue };

const addNewTag = () => {
    if (tagValue !== "") {
      tagArr.push(obj);
    }
};

addNewTag();

console.log(tagArr);
```

и в массив `tagArr` все записалось

Comment: Она вызывается при клике на кнопку, странный вопрос)

Comment: да, а я по коду и не увидел что там какой-то клик подразумевается

Answer (score 0):

вы используете `setTagValue`? если нет, то логично что `tagValue` пустой и это условие не проходит `if (tagValue !== "") { ...`

Comment: сеттер считывает значение из инпута, я закидываю его в объект, объект в условие и пушу в массив

Comment: ну так добавьте это в ваш вопрос, откуда я знаю каким образом вы это делаете? добавьте код

Answer (score -1):

Массивy нужно дать состояние, и перезаписывать его каждый раз при добавлении нового значения:

```
  let [tagArr, setTagArr] = React.useState([]);
  let [tagValue, setTagValue] = React.useState("");

  let obj = { value: tagValue };
  const addNewTag = () => {
    if (tagValue !== "") {
      tagArr.push(obj);
      setTagArr([...tagArr]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Зачем вы мутируете состояние в данной строке `tagArr.push(obj)` ? Используйте только сеттер для изменения состояния, в данном случае `setTagArr`